# Complex Singularities and residue question

Tags: complex-integration, analytic-functions, singularity, cauchy-principal-value

> Given the function
>   $$F(z)= \frac{z^2}{((z^2)+1)^2(z^2+2z+2)},$$
>   determine its singularities and then calculate the corresponding residues.

Finding the zeros i got $\pm i$ and $-1\pm i$ for pole with order $2$ and simple pole, respectively. 
Calculating the residue for the simple pole and pole with order $2$, I got $\pm \frac{2i}{2i+1}$, and $±\frac{4}{4i-3}$ respectively.

I have a feeling my work is not correct, so any help or correction would be appreciated

Also would it be a removable singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: Whether or not $0$ is a removable singularity depends on the domain of $F$, which you have not specified.The formula for $F(x)$ is can define an analytic  function on $\mathbb C$  \ $\{ \pm i, -1\pm i \}$ with no singularity at $0$.

Comment: Please show us your work.  Otherwise, if you are wrong, no one can tell what your errors were. If you are right, no one can tell whether you did it right  or were lucky. Physicists (even Einstein) have a talent for making mathematical errors that cancel each other out.

Comment: For simple poles using the formula, Lim[(z-(−1±i))f(z)]
For pole of order 2 I used Lim[ 1/(2-1)! d/dz ((z-(±i))^2 f(z)] @user254665